# What do you call the device that holds your eyes open?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the device that holds your eyes open? What do you call them? Is there a particular word that's used to refer to it? I tried to google it, but I came with absolutely no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**opthalmic speculum** or **eye speculum**

https://www.surgicalinstruments.com/eye-instruments/eye-speculums

http://www.katalystsurgical.com/instruments/speculum

> Surgical Eye Specula or Ophthalmic Speculums are used for retracting
>   and holding the eyelid during surgery

https://www.titanmedicalshop.com/collections/speculums

and see also

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_instruments_used_in_ophthalmology

Comment: Is there a generic word for the thing that holds it into place, like the tips?

Comment: "Speculum" is the general medical term for a particular type of device like this, which holds things open or apart. But I don't know how many people would necessarily know that. (Most women have probably encountered a speculum when receiving regular medical exams, but even then I don't know how many would know that it's a more general term that you could use for the eye-opening device also.)